# Unpivoiting a Pandas Dataframe with removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

I have the following dataframe:

| Material | End Date | Start Date | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10-Dec | 10-Dec | 4 |
| B | 13-Dec | 14-Dec | 2 |
| C | 14-Dec | 16-Dec | 3 |
| D | 15-Dec | 15-Dec | 0 |
| E | 16-Dec | 17-Dec | 1 |

I want to unpivot this dataframe in a way that gives me the output:
Here where the end date and start date is same, should not be printed twice.

| Material | Date | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10-Dec | 4 |
| B | 13-Dec | 2 |
| B | 14-Dec | 2 |
| C | 14-Dec | 3 |
| C | 15-Dec | 3 |
| C | 16-Dec | 3 |
| D | 15-Dec | 0 |
| E | 16-Dec | 1 |
| E | 17-Dec | 1 |

Can I get the code for this ?

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=["Material", "Qty"], value_vars=["End Date", "Start Date"], value_name="Date").drop("variable", axis=1)` ?

Comment: `df.melt(id_vars=["Material", "Qty"], value_vars=["End Date", "Start Date"], value_name="Date").drop("variable", axis=1).drop_duplicates()` ?